# How extract css code on the server side that is used from css/scss files?

Tags: reactjs, node.js

Within the scope of my task, I need to extract CSS code from templates ( react components ) on the server side (using Express/Nest). I found an approach that suggests using Emotion for these purposes, and it seems to be compatible only with **MUI styled/Emotion styled** but not with regular CSS files.

**Example:**
1)https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/server-rendering/
2)https://emotion.sh/docs/ssr

The challenge is that all my components already use styles pulled from module.css files.
So my question is, is it possible to extract these styles on the server side?

( Why do I need this? I'm preparing templates for printing PDF files using Puppeteer, which, in turn, is a separate application. That's why I need to have separate HTML and CSS that I can feed into this application. )